# I am facing this error "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" while trying to add two integer values in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a banking program for my learning project. I was trying to add two integers while in the deposit method. This is the code -

```
    from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
from random import randint


class Account(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def createAccount(self):
        return 0

    @abstractmethod
    def authenticate(self):
        return 0

    @abstractmethod
    def withdraw(self):
        return 0

    @abstractmethod
    def deposit(self):
        return 0

    @abstractmethod
    def displayBalance(self):
        return 0


class SavingsAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self):
        self.savingsAccount = {}

    def createAccount(self, name, initialDeposit):
        self.accountNumber = randint(10000, 99999)
        self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber] = [name, initialDeposit]
        print("This your new accountNumber: ", self.accountNumber)

    def authenticate(self, name, accountNumber):
        if accountNumber in self.savingsAccount.keys():
            if self.savingsAccount[accountNumber][0] == name:
                print("Authentication Successful")
                self.accountNumber = self.accountNumber
                return True
            else:
                print("Authentication Failed")
                return False
        else:
            print("Authentication Failed")
            return False

    def withdraw(self, withdrawalAmount):
        if withdrawalAmount > self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1]:
            print("Insufficient balance")
        else:
            self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1] -= withdrawalAmount
            self.displayBalance()

    def deposit(self, depositAmount):
        self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1] = self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1] + depositAmount
        self.displayBalance()

    def displayBalance(self):
        print("The balance in your account: ", self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1])


savingsAccount = SavingsAccount()
while True:
    userChoice = int(input('''
    Enter 1 to create a new account
    Enter 2 to access an already created account
    Enter 3 to exit'''))
    if userChoice == 1:
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        initialDeposit = input("Enter your initial deposit: ")
        savingsAccount.createAccount(name, initialDeposit)
    elif userChoice == 2:
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        accountNumber = int(input("Enter your account number: "))
        authenticationStatus = savingsAccount.authenticate(name, accountNumber)
        if authenticationStatus is True:
            while True:
                action = int(input('''
                Enter 1 to withdraw
                Enter 2 to deposit
                Enter 3 to display account balance
                 Enter 4 to exit to previous menu: '''))
                if action == 1:
                    withdrawalAmount = int(input("Enter your withdrawal amount: "))
                    savingsAccount.withdraw(withdrawalAmount)
                elif action == 2:
                    depositAmount = int(input("Enter deposit amount: "))
                    savingsAccount.deposit(depositAmount)
                elif action == 3:
                    savingsAccount.displayBalance()
                elif action == 4:
                    break
        else:
            pass
```

It is showing me this error statement -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mudit\PycharmProjects\testProject\app.py", line 90, in <module>
    savingsAccount.deposit(depositAmount)
  File "C:\Users\mudit\PycharmProjects\testProject\app.py", line 57, in deposit
    self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1] = self.savingsAccount[self.accountNumber][1] + depositAmount
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

In the deposit and withdraw method when I am trying to add the two integer values, it is showing me that the variables displayAmount and withdrawAmount are strings, but I have clearly converted them to integers through 'int'
Please tell what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please limit your code to the relevant parts: make a [mcve].

Comment: `initialDeposit = input("Enter your initial deposit: ")` here, `initialDeposit` is a string because `input` returns only strings.

Comment: It is working now! thanks

Comment: @88keysintheZone You forgot to add the functionality to terminate the program when `3` is entered. Import `sys` and use `sys.exit()` to terminate the program when `3` is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Bruh, you forgot to add int in the initialDeposit variable

```
if userChoice == 1:
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        initialDeposit = int(input("Enter your initial deposit: ")) # <= Add int here
        savingsAccount.createAccount(name, initialDeposit)
```

Comment: That helped i was being stupid! Sorry still a beginner